# The Same But Different Animal

Tags: riddle

I have two forms one bigger than the other.
One is always hungry the other is always stuffed.
One is very cuddly. The other is strong and rough. Especially if it is female.
What am I?

Comment: I edited to give it a little more structure. Please feel free to roll-back if you prefer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are a

> A Bear (Teddy Bear and Real Bear)

I have two forms one bigger than the other.

> A stuffed bear (teddy bear) and a real bear.

One is always hungry the other is always stuffed.

> Bears are constantly eating, while teddy bears are always stuffed (with fluff).

One is very cuddly. The other is strong and rough. Especially if it is female.

> Snuggle with your teddy, but don't fight a real bear, especially "mamma bear"